# Update Lightning API Version

Tags: lightning, api, security-review, opencti

I need to update lightning API version to 40 or more for Open CTI components as it is the requirement of security review. Currently, I have version 38.0. I wanted to know how can I update API version.

Can we follow the approach of updating it via apex query?

Something as this:

```
List<AuraDefinitionBundle> obj = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName, ApiVersion, Description FROM AuraDefinitionBundle WHERE DeveloperName = 'demoAdapterOut'];

obj[0].ApiVersion = 40.0;
Update obj;
```

For testing when I executed this query, I got error `DML operation Update not allowed on List<AuraDefinitionBundle>`

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: You'll need to use Metadata API in order to perform this update

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Can you please provide some sample for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

Go to Developer Console, open component. On the right side, click **Bundle Version Settings**. Set the version you want from dropdown list, click Save.